# TableViewController doesn't display information on table

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi when I do for loop to get all documents from a collection. I add the car object to the NSMutablearray and when I debug i can see that the objects are being added to the array but when i want it to display in the table and get the count of the array I call the [self.mycars count] to get the count but the count is nil and i cant get information from the cell.textLabel.text = vehicle.name; so what am i doing wrong.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Car.h"
#import "Vehicle.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.db = [FIRFirestore firestore];
    self.myCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [[[[self.db collectionWithPath:@"users"] documentWithPath:[FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid]
      collectionWithPath:@"cars"] getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);
        } else {
            for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents) {
                NSLog(@"%@ => %@", document.documentID, document.data);
                Car *car = [[Car alloc] initWithCarName:[document valueForField:@"carname"] andCarStyle:[document valueForField:@"carstyle"]
                                           andCarColour:[document valueForField:@"colour"] andCarYear:[document valueForField:@"caryear"]
                                            andCarDoors:[document valueForField:@"doors"] andCarSeat:[document valueForField:@"seat"] andCarWheels:[document valueForField:@"wheels"]
                                     andCarTankCapacity:[document valueForField:@"tankcapacity"] andCarHorsePower:[document valueForField:@"horsepower"] andCarModelName:[document valueForField:@"modelname"]];

                NSLog(@"Car name:%@", car.name);

                [self.myCars addObject:car];

            }
        }
    }];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.myCars count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...'
    Vehicle *vehicle = [self.myCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = vehicle.name;

    return cell;
}



@end
```

Comment: It's missing a `[tableView reloadData];` done in main thread, once you did the `for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents)` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload data manually after changing/updating your datasource (`self.myCars` in this case) which mean you need to add `[self.tableView reloadData];` after for loop. If it still is not working, you might want to check if `self.myCars` is initialized yet.